# Date command and the file containing system date

Tags: date, time

Seems simple, but couldn't find any answer:

Is it possible to edit a file for the purpose of updating the Linux date instead of using `date +%y%m%d -s "DATE"` command?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do? Modify a date within a file? Modify the created/accessed time?

Comment: are you trying to set the system time & date based on the contents of a file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Actually I want to know which file contains system time and date and whether it is possible to manually edit this file or not by vim editor for example.

Comment: @bu5hman, I think my comment to Jeff clarifies my purpose

Comment: @A.A Clarifications should be made to the question, not left in comments where they may be ignored. Also, what makes you believe that the system time is stored in a file somewhere?

Comment: @Kusalananda, ya... I thought in the wrong way. It's not reasonable to store the system time in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no file representing the current system time on Linux. Linux gets the current time from the RTCs (real-time clocks) or from external sources like NTP servers, and then keeps track of it internally. The file-like representations of the RTC (`/dev/rtc*`) are used for configuring and recieving alarms, and can't be used for setting the time. The RTC status file (`/proc/driver/rtc`) is read-only. See [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt) for details.

Comment: I thought that the command "hwclock --systohc" writes the system clock to RTC, ya?

Comment: So? What of it?

Comment: And maybe the "date" command could have a representation file somewhere.
Anyway, thank you for your answer. I'm a noob and I must go through the kernel documentation.

Comment: Both use system calls. `date` uses the [`clock_settime(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) function. You can use `strace` to examine what the commands actually do.